# Xcode cached wrong search paths

Tags: ios, xcode

I've spent a day trying to figure why Xcode doesn't find my framework headers but couldn't solve the problem. In a nutshell, my project name contains spaces like `My Sample App` therefore I got errors that my added frameworks header files not found. Before `Xcode 6.3.1` I could solve the problem with deleting and importing the SDKs again. But with the newest version it doesn't work anymore. I could reproduce and solve the problem with a sample project where I changed the `Framework Search Path` to `$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)` also set project dir to `recursive`. However it doesn't want to work in my other project and I have zero idea why this happens. Is it possible that Xcode cached somewhere a wrong path? Or can I reset everything somehow? It's very frustrating, for example I get an error that `"Parse.h" not found` so I delete the Parse framework, close Xcode, open it again and run. This time the error is correct, because there is no Parse sdk, then I import it again, run the app and the build fails and I get the same error. I tried to copy the folders to the project folder and also tried to add them from elsewhere but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include paths with spaces in them, wrap them in quotes. I suggest using `$(SRCROOT)` as the root directory. For example:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/My Headers/"
```

Assuming your project directory is "My Sample App", this will resolve to something like (just an example):

```
/Users/bushiko/Projects/My Sample App/My Headers/
```